# How to find all values in word by using regexp in MongoDB?

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's say I have the following string in MongoDB document:

```
{"name": "space delimited string"}
```

I need to build mongodb query with `regexp` to find this document by entering the following search request:

`space string`

It look like `LIKE` operator in RDBS. I know that there is latest MongoDB 3 with full-text search but I need `regexp` due current outdated version.

Please help me to construct mongodb query with `regexp` to find document by entering the search above.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it there are a couple of options.

If you mean "AND" for **all** words then use positive lookahead:

```js
{ "name": /(?=.*\bspace\b)(?=.*\bstring\b).+/ }
```

or if an [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator suits you better:

```js
{ "name": { "$all": [/\bspace\b/,/\bstrig\b/] } }
```

And if you mean "OR" for **either** of the words then you can do:

```js
{ "name": /\bspace\b|\bstring\b/ }
```

or use an [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator:

```js
{ "name": { "$in": [/\bspace\b/,/\bstring\b/] } }
```

Noting that in all cases you likely want those `\b` boundary matches in there to delimit the "word", or otherwise you are getting "partial" words.

So it depends on which you mean and which suits you best. You can construct the regular expression using its own syntaxt to either mean "AND" or "OR", or alternately you can just use the equivalent MongoDB logical expresions ( `$all` or `$in` ) that take a "list" of regular expressions instead.

So build a string for regex or build a list. Your choice.

---

Naturally of course you need to "break up" a string into the "words" in order to process. Lacking an a language tag here, but as a JavaScript example:

**As a single regular expression for "AND"**:

```js
var searchString = "space string";

var expression = new RegExp(
    "" + searchString.split(" ").map(function(word) {
        return "(?=.*\\b" + word + "\\b)"
    }).join("") + ".+"
)

var query = { "name": expression };
```

**Or for an "OR" condition on a single expression**:

```js
var expression = new RegExp(
    searchString.split(" ").map(function(word) {
        return "\\b" + word + "\\b"
    }).join("|")
);

var query = { "name": expression };
```

**Or as a list of expressions:**

```js
var type = "AND",
    query = { "name": {} };

// List of expressions
var list = searchString.split(" ").map(function(word) {
    return new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b")
});

// Determine operator based on type
query.name[( type === "AND") ? "$all" : "$in"] = list;
```